# Shipping Rate Calculating for given Country,State,Postcode and Price

Tags: magento

I am trying on module for shipping rate calculation like ***Estimate Shipping.***

I have 4 text-boxes, One for country, one for state, one for postcode, last
one for Price. Here customer choose the state and country, enter the Postcode 
and Price.

After submit form i need to calculate shipping rate price for that 
provided data.

Here have only one shipping rate ***(Table rate)*** enabled.

Please any one help me

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Magento Website Admin -> Configuration -> Shipping Methods -> Table Rates ->

- Enable: yes
- Title:  Summer Discount
- Method Name: Free Shipping (your choice)
- Condition: Weight vs. Destination

and set the Current Configuration Scope is "Main Website"

then show that, Export: "Export CSV" button 
Click the button, and downloaded .csv file, 
next edit this file with available area zipcodes
next save and import to upload this file and click "Save Config".

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to decide what shipping carrier you want to use? each shipping carrier have they own Web API, all the codes and documentation on their websites... just Google it.

ex. [USPS](https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/welcome.htm) >> [Documentation](https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/rate-calculator-api.pdf)